# matplotlib and seaborn heatmap renders differently in Jupyter to savefig (labels cut off)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, heatmap, seaborn

Using Jupyter 4.4.0 and Python 3.6.5 (Anaconda), I am generating a heatmap as follows:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate a 9x4 matrix of random values and long labels
x,y = 9,4
plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))
scores = np.random.random((y, x))
cols = ['looooooooooong_label_x_%d' % i for i in range(x)]
rows = ['looooooooooong_label_y_%d' % i for i in reversed(range(y))]

# generate a heatmap using seaborn with rotated labels
ax = sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=cols, index=rows), annot=True, square=True, cbar=False,  cmap='YlGnBu', xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0, fontsize=8)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, fontsize=8, rotation_mode='anchor', ha='right')
```

In the notebook, Jupyter automatically renders this image as shown:

[image: Jupyter-rendered seaborn/matplotlib heatmap]

This looks exactly as I want it to. However, when I take the next step and save the plot to file with:

```py
ax.figure.savefig('hmx.png')
```

This file appears as:

[image: seaborn/matplotlib heatmap saved to PNG directly]

Differences appear to be:

- The saved image appears to be shifted down and to the left, cutting off the labels;
- The Jupyter-rendered PNG has a transparent background, and the saved image does not (it has a white background).

I would like to know how to save the image generated by Jupyter to file, or better yet, what I am doing wrong when I try to save the PNG myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed!

```py
ax.figure.savefig('hmx.png', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The output now matches what Jupyter generated: transparent, and correctly aligned without any labels cut off:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this!! fixed the same issue I was having